# how to use TS+css+scss in react SSR framework next?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I'm am using TS + CSS + SCSS in nextJS. I will import some CSS files, but I want to set `cssModule:false` to those CSS files, then I will import my own SCSS files and set `cssModule:true`.

The below is my code in `next.config.js`, it transfers CSS files to module.

```
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
const withTypescript = require("@zeit/next-typescript");
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
module.exports = withTypescript(
    withCSS(
      withSass({
        cssModules: true
      })
    )
);
```

Could you please advise me on the right approach of importing CSS files?

Comment: i am using antd,so i import the css file like this:   `import "antd/dist/antd.css";`

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of `next-css` is global, you either using `cssModules` or not.

My solution for this was to configure webpack manually to not apply `cssModules` on files with `.global.css` suffix.

```
config.module.rules.forEach(rule => {
  if (rule.test.toString().includes('.scss')) {
    rule.rules = rule.use.map(useRule => {
      if (typeof useRule === 'string') {
        return {
          loader: useRule,
        };
      }
      if (useRule.loader.startsWith('css-loader')) {
        return {
          oneOf: [
            {
              test: /\.global\.scss$/,
              loader: useRule.loader,
              options: {
                ...useRule.options,
                modules: false,
              },
            },
            {
              loader: useRule.loader,
              options: useRule.options,
            },
          ],
        };
      }

      return useRule;
    });

    delete rule.use;
  }
});
```

There is an [open PR](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/pull/372#issuecomment-485235941) for next-css to include similar solution to the lib.